# Will duplicate articles with links in them pointing to my site harm my SEO after Google's Penguin 2.1 update?

Tags: seo, backlinks, google-panda-algorithm, link-building

After Google's latest updates, previous methods of link building aren't working, like social bookmarking, comment, forum profiles, etc... Therefore I started cleaning up some spammy or low-quality links.

I also posted some articles on article posting websites. But I posted duplicate articles in several of them with my site's links in them. Now I really don't know whether I should remove those articles or not to recover from Google's Penguin update.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This question in its current form is a little difficult to understand. Please edit to just one (clear) question that can be answered factually.

Comment: I made the changes.

Comment: Made additional edits for you and reopened.

Answer (score 1):

[Search Engine Watch claims](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2271305/Google-Penguin-2.0-Casualties-Why-Sites-Got-Hit) that article marketing sites got hit by penguin 2.0.

Here is an article that discusses [article marketing post Penguin](http://sitesprint.com/article-marketing-after-google-penguin/).  It says that it can still be done but recommends caution:

> - Use [only] the best [article directory].
> - Publish high quality, unique articles
> - Diversify your anchor text
> - Diversify the linked domains. (Try to get links from more authority sites.)
> - [Limit the use of exact match anchor text]

Based on these references, article marketing can negatively impact your site regarding the Penguin algorithms.   The duplicate articles that you mention specifically go against the guidelines spelled out above.  If you were hit by Penguin and have done article marketing, I would recommend removing those articles as part of recovery.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate content is generally a bad idea. I would get the duplicate removed. Also it is wise to be careful when guest posting with keyword rich anchor text for links. You should diversify anchor text.